# How to call function inside a firefox add on from another firefox add on

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-applications, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am working on a project in my company and I have to decide on whether to build a web application or a firefox add on that would be then published.

The major motivation behind building a firefox addon is being able to call functions inside other add ons.

Excuse me if I am saying something stupid, I have no experience with firefox or add ons and couldn't find anything useful. I would be very grateful for any information, or even a hint on where to start my research.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: you might want to start with writing [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) [scripts](http://userscripts.org/) first..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer 1 is more of an old-school approach to building add-ons for Firefox. There is a newer, more web-like api Mozilla has been working on called the Add-on SDK:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/index.html#getting-started

Answer (score 1):

This is the place you need to go if you need information on building Firefox addons or extensions

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_an_Extension

And MDN docs are one of the most complete docs for JavaScript, which you will be using a lot for the extension. Most of your doubts should be cleared there.